# How can I install curl on Windows to use with C

Tags: c, windows, curl, mingw

I need to install curl on Windows to use it in a C application, I am using MinGW. Detailed instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't include `curl`, but there is `wget` in GnuWin32 (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I am aware of that, however I need curl...

Comment: Any particular reason you're asking about the application _curl_ vs the library _libcurl_? I would imagine the library to be more useful for programming.

Comment: My mistake, I was referring to the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the library [download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and under "Win32 - Generic" download the libcurl option. This zip file includes headers and libraries in the .a format. Extract the files and use them in your project.

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for the [source code](http://curl.haxx.se/dev/source.html)? Win32 2000/XP 7.21.7 libcurl is the option which includes the headers and .a files.

Comment: I mean how do I use the binary? Sorry I'm new to C...

Comment: You need to add some options to your MinGW command:t o include the headers add "-I%PATH_TO_HEADERS%", to link to the library add "-l%PATH_TO_LIBCURL%". The first one is an upper case i the second is a lower case L.